# Loading Spinner While Waiting for Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've just run into a very strange error. I am not allowed to post any of the code, so I will attempt to explain it as best as possible:

I have just implemented and tested an Activity that essentially creates a list with ListView using a custom ArrayAdapter and layouts. Simple. Now, I've attempted to turn the activity into a fragment. I've looked through quite a number of tutorials and I feel that I've gotten most of the code right. I have a main activity that adds the ListFragment from before to a FrameLayout, and all the data still loads into the list (I know because of the debugger), but after all the initialization is completed, all I see on the device is a loading spinner...I haven't implemented a loading spinner anywhere in my code. Has anyone else run into this problem or can give me some insight? Any information is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListFragment displays an indeterminate progress bar when there is no data to be shown. Did you call `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter after the data got loaded to populate the list?

without code we cant say much but that sounds like your problem

Comment: including this and making a small change in onCreateView seems to have done the trick! thanks!